# Не работает обработчик закрытия lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Это Lightbox, рядом с большим изображением есть кнопка, при клике на которую Lightbox скрывается, но почему-то не работает обработчик на кнопку.

```
$(document).ready(function (){   
   $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {

            $('.wrap').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');

            $('#lightbox').show();
        }

        else { 
            var lightbox = 
            '<div id="lightbox">' +
                                    '<div class="wrap">' +
                    '<img src="' + image_href +'" />' +
                        '</div>'+ '<button id="close">Закрыть</button>' +
            '</div>';

            $('body').append(lightbox);
        }

    });

    $('#close').bind('click', function() {
        $('#lightbox').hide();
    });
        });
```

Comment: Открываете консоль браузера и дописываете в свой вопрос имеющиеся там ошибки.

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что ничего не происходит, Lightbox появился и не исчезает при клике на кнопку, только при перезагрузке, в консоли ничего нет.

Comment: @Black Fire, добавьте в bind('click', function() { console.log('test') - так проверьте работает ли вообще клик, если нет повесьте обработчик на document и через него на #close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, вроде работает:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){   
   $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {

            $('.wrap').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');

            $('#lightbox').show();
        }

        else { 
            var lightbox = 
            '<div id="lightbox">' +
                                    '<div class="wrap">' +
                    '<img src="' + image_href +'" />' +
                        '</div>'+ '<button id="close">Закрыть</button>' +
            '</div>';

            $('body').append(lightbox);
        }

    });
    $(document).on('click','#close', function(){
        console.log(true);
        $('#lightbox').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.lightbox_trigger{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lightbox_trigger">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Да, только что рыскал в документации jQuery и нашёл.